# jquery cookie array loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, cookies, each

I'm trying to read an array from a cookie like this:

```
var arr = $.makeArray($.cookie("mycookie"));

jQuery.each(arr, function() {
  $('#' + this).removeClass('collapsed');
});
```

The problem is it works only with the first item from the array. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$.makeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray) doesn't magically turn strings into arrays. It's for converting array-like objects into proper JavaScript arrays. Example:

```
> $.makeArray('a b c d')
  ["a b c d"]
```

...which is probably not what you're looking for.

Your question does not include what the value of `$.cookie("mycookie")` is, but assuming it's something like `'a b c d'`, you can just use [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split):

```
var arr = $.cookie("mycookie").split(' ');

jQuery.each(arr, function() {
  $('#' + this).removeClass('collapsed');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I have a better understanding. The value of the cookie is 'a,b,c,d'

Comment: Okay, then just use `.split(',')` - it sounds like you already figured that out, though.